# PHP_APC extension causes error in WAMP server

Tags: php, caching, apc

I have Windows 2003 Webserver with Apache 2.2.23 and php 5.3.18 VC9 ts on the boart. When I add php_apc 3.1.9 extension, it works over an hour and shuts down Apache. I can only restart apache with stop and start buttons on Apache Monitor, because restart button popups error message and fails Apache. New beta versions of apc don't work, neither does older. Maybe new version of php conflicts with apc? I have no other idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often reason to happen such error is if you have PHP Thread safe and you trying to set not tread safe extension or opposite...

Get both thread safe and non thread safe apc extensions and try to run your apache with each of them..

Comment: I wonder where I can download thread-safe versions of apc (and how do I know that this extensions is ts). By the way, my previous version of php 5.3.13 ts VC9 worked with php_apc 3.1.9 just fine.

Comment: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ Perhaps you have changed your PHP from TS to Non TS or from Non TS to TS..  I don't know :)

Comment: I've already used previous link before. No luck. After cleaning symfony 2 cache, it shows "The procedure entry point ReleaseSRWLockExclusive could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll" warning, and it doesn't seem to be working regarding to phpinfo(). And I'm sure, that my version of php is thread-safe. Any ideas?

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61984 Try to find your bug in google.. 
check 4th answer There is version for 2003

Comment: I got it working with this build http://belsky.info/uploads/my/bugz/61984/php_apc-3.1.10-5.3-vc9-x86-xp.zip     Thanks a lot!